# Inverse of $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2$)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)$.

Am I correct in thinking that $f$ has no inverse?

I can show that $f$ is one-to-one but $f$ is not onto since for $(1,2)$ in the codomain, there is no $(x,y)$ in the domain such that $f(x,y)=(1,2)$. So $f$ does not have any inverse.

Comment: you can restrict to the image of $f$.

Comment: @Arian That is not my question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do not see why it does not hold. I picked $(1,2)$ in the codomain which is $\mathbb{R}^2$ not the domain. I think your are mixing codomain with domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; that function, with the specified codomain, has no inverse, because it is not surjective.

Many people will, however, construct something very like an inverse for it, namely, an inverse that maps from $K$ to $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, where $K$ is the *image* of the domain under $f$, and they are likely to informally call this thing an "inverse".

Comment: by the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem we can say that it has no inverse at $(0,0)$? As $D=-8xy$

Comment: No; that only lets you say that the inverse (if any),  is non-differentiable at that point.

Comment: Forgot it is a sufficient condition only